# Missing application (gizmo, gizmote) when searching the Android market from an HTC Wildfire

Tags: android

I'm not quite sure where to turn for this one. I have been in touch with the developers who have no clue why this is happening.

Basically, I'm a consumer with an HTC Wildfire running Android 2.1. I connect via Orange in the UK. The app I'm after is Gizmo or Gizmote from a company called JRiver. Its an extension to their Media Centre software.

Problem is, when I search for the app on the market from the phone, any results that are returned is nothing to do with the app I'm after. I only get a few results from Gizmo and nothing for Gizmote. So far, no other users have experienced this issue from the JRiver forums.

Apparently the app should be compatible with 2.1 so I have no idea why it doesn't even show up. Can anyone throw any pointer on this?

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site for programming-related questions. You will have better luck asking in sites like: http://android.stackexchange.com/